# htaccess 301 redirect trouble

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to redirect old addresses to new, friendly addresses:
Firstly, I put a `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteRule product-(.*)-(.*)$ product2.php?name=$1&code=$2 #Friendly URL includes the name and the code
RewriteRule product-(.*)$ product2.php?code=$1 #some products do not have a name, so they are identified only by their code
```

The code written above works fine, but I want to `Redirect` the old non-friendly addresses (for example Google is still indexing the old addresses and it needs to know the new URL's):

```
Redirect /product.php?cod=130ps /product-code-130PS
Redirect /product.php?cod=140ps /product-name-blah-blah-code-140PS
```

This doesn't work. I get a 404 error. If I create `product.php` file, it will display the content from that file.

**Edit:**
I made some redirects for product categories list:

```
RewriteRule product-category-name$ prodlist.php?ctg=30
#...
Redirect /prodlist.php?ctg=30 /product-category-name
```

Those are working...

Note: non-www URL's are redirected to www URL's.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sounds like PHP isn't correctly installed/enabled.

Comment: It is a paid hosting... Should I configure `php.ini` somehow?

Comment: You should probably stick an `[L]` flag on the end of those rules.

Comment: I've tried `[L]`, then `[R=301,L]` . There was no change ...